# How to close arrows when we switched the workspaces 17.10

Tags: 17.10, 17.04, workspaces

I want to remove arrows on screen when I switched the workspaces. How can I do that ?

(You know up or down arrows appear on screen when we switched the workspaces)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @pomsky here is ss https://i.hizliresim.com/qGzrN5.png

Comment: These arrows disappear after a few seconds, on their own, yes? Are you switching workspaces using the keyboard, or by clicking on a workspace in overview mode (or using `Workspaces to Dock` GNOME extension, https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/427/workspaces-to-dock/)?

Comment: yes they are disappear in a few seconds automaticly. I'm using short keys like ctr + 1 for workspace one @heynnema

Comment: @pomsky sorry I will edit the question, hizliresim is kind of imgur in here

Comment: I think that you mean either control+alt+[1-4] or control+alt+[up|down arrow]. Does the arrow display for a couple of seconds bother you that much? How will you know what workspace that you land on without it?

Comment: See https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/758/no-workspace-switcher-popup/ or https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/959/disable-workspace-switcher-popup/

Comment: ohh thank you but how can I install this extension ? I never use extension before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Look at either of these extensions:**

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/758/no-workspace-switcher-popup/

[image]

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/959/disable-workspace-switcher-popup/

[image]

When viewing the web pages at the above links, click the OFF slider to ON. Only enable one at a time.

**To view your installed extensions:**

https://extensions.gnome.org/local/